# Hadoop replication not working properly

Tags: memory, hadoop, local-storage, hdfs

I have a cluster of two machines, one as master, and two as slave (the master as slave also). I have set the replication factor to 1 in both machines. Hive is also configured on master. After a few days, my hard disk become full (no space left), and then I ran the following command:

```
hadoop dfs -setrep -w 1 -R /
```

and after executing this command, considerable storage became available.
Why is this? I know the `setrep` command is used to set the replication factor of each block to 1. When I put a condition in configuration then what is this? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: how have you set the replication factor to 1? can you post a snippet?

Comment: In hdfs-site.xml following code is added for setrep                       <property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>

Answer (score 0):

You need to setrep in config file and restart the cluster

```
<property> 
   <name>dfs.replication</name> 
   <value>1</value> 
</property>
```

Comment: If you read my question statement completely, then I mentioned that I have done it already then why it is happening

Comment: -setrep -w 1 property will change the replication factor to a new one. may be. If you have different value other than default. Hope you already have your answer.